# Using DATEFROMPARTS with RIGHT/CHARINDEX function

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

Alright so I'm re-writing some scripts that were provided to me and part of the script is constructing a date from two different columns, one of which could contain data such as this `3|15` and then that constructed date is being compared to today's date.

Original query section:

```
CASE WHEN rs.RecurrencePattern = 'Monthly'  AND DAYDIFF((CreateDate(GetYear(rs.ws_wg_mig_start_date),GetMonth(rs.ws_wg_mig_start_date), toint(StrParts(rs.RecurrencePatternParms, '|',1)))),(now())) < 0 THEN GetMonth(rs.ws_wg_mig_start_date)+1
```

I think this is MySQL but I'm not real sure. I'm trying to recreate this in SQL Server and so far I'm using DATEFROMPARTS and stringing everything together. I'm using a NULLIF(CHARINDEX to get the value after the `|` but if it doesn't exist, then the whole date field is null. I need another pair of eyes on this before I go insane.

Current SQL Code:

```
DATEFROMPARTS(datepart(year,rs.ws_wg_mig_start_date),datepart(month,rs.ws_wg_mig_start_date),Convert(int,Right(recurrence_pattern_params, NULLIF(CHARINDEX('|', reverse(recurrence_pattern_params)),0)-1)))
```

Comment: `'3|15'` is not a date as far as I'm concerned.  More explanation is needed.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Right. That's why I'm converting it here: `Convert(int,Right(recurrence_pattern_params,` If the `|` exists, then I need to grab the characters to the right of that. If it doesn't exist, then I just need whatever is in that column. So if the values are `2019-07-01 00:00:00.000` in the ws_wg_mig_start_date field and `1|15` in the recurrence_pattern_params field, the end result is 2019-07-15. If `1` is the value in recurrence_pattern_params, then 2019-07-01